# Css selector take a spesific src in img Cheerio

Tags: jquery, css, node.js, express, cheerio

I don't know how to take specific src

```
const img1 = selector
  .find("li.gallery_thumbItem.s-gallery_thumbItem:nth-child(3) span.gallery_thumbIn> img:last-child")
  .attr("src");
```

This html page:

[image: result]

but just wanna take first img from html and this is the results from scraping I got,

[image: html]

actually i just wanna take this
[image: inginkan]

Comment: Your results seem to be correct. What's not working or what were you expecting to happen? Too many results? Too few? Incorrect?

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
const img1 = selector.find(".gallery_thumbItem.s-gallery_thumbItem:nth-child(3) img[src$='.jpg']:last").attr("src");
```

As the others are `.gif` images, it would ignore those. With these filtered out, you would only have the `.jpg` item.

See More: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/